# Strophe and JSON Messages

Tags: json, escaping, xmpp, strophe

Im having problems to send a simple json message to other xmpp user using strophe. The command to create the message:

`var json_stringified_msg = '{"type":"ola"}';`

var reply = $msg({to: this.m_user, from: this.jid_connection, type: 'chat'}).c("body").t(json_stringified_msg);

connection.send(reply.tree());

The problem is that in the other side the client receives in the chat:
{"ACTION"quot;CHANGE_MODE", "MODE"quot;KEYBOARD"}

I can't make the unescape from the other side because its a closed client.

How to send exactly the json message to the other side?

Thanks for your help.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

RFC6121 states:

The  element contains human-readable XML character data that specifies the textual contents of the message.

and it also states:

The  element MUST NOT contain mixed content (as defined in Section 3.2.2 of [XML]).

i dont think your JSON is getting changed to a string.

You can read it from here: http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#message-syntax-body

Answer (score 0):

I modified strophe.js:

```
t: function (text)
{
    //var child = Strophe.xmlTextNode(text);
    var child = Strophe.xmlGenerator().createTextNode(text);
    this.node.appendChild(child);
    return this;
}
```

and it works fine for me.